# phone call doesn't work iOS 10

Tags: objective-c, ios10, phone-call

```
NSURL *phoneNumber = [NSURL URLWithString:@"telprompt://966555551111"];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:phoneNumber];
```

I am trying to make a call I a button action but in addition to it's deprecated, it doesn't make a call

Answer (score 0):

[OpenURL is deprecated in iOS 10](https://useyourloaf.com/blog/openurl-deprecated-in-ios10/)

So

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"tel:966555551111"] options:@{} completionHandler:^(BOOL success) {
    if (success) {
        NSLog(@"Opened url");
    }
}];
```

Check with your real time device.Don't check with simulator.